# Missing Sitecore Toolbar in Content tree

Tags: content-editor

The content editor toolbar is missing after clicking the Item unable to navigate to any toolbar or publish the Item.

Initial Home screen:

[image]

After clicking any item in content tree: All toolbar labels disappears

[image]

Console Error:

[image]

Also Added language resolver in last release thinking that might cause this issue Config:

```
  <processor type="Foundation.LanguageResolver.LanguageEnforcer"  patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
```

setting Context lang:

```
    Sitecore.Context.SetLanguage(AltLanguage, true);
```

Please let me know the fix to resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you have any console errors or errors in the Sitecore logs?

Comment: updated the console error message

Comment: Also Added language resolver in last release thinking that might cause this issue Config:    <processor type="Foundation.LanguageResolver.LanguageEnforcer"  patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']"/> setting Context lang:

Answer (score 6):

The issue you are experiencing is due to the language cookie. Normally, there need to be a cookie which stores the language. This is a known issue on Sitecore.

Please contact Sitecore Support and ask them about the patch

- Sitecore.Support.100371.100542

This patch contains one config file and one dll file.

If you are using the Sitecore 8.2 Update 1, you can download the patch at https://sitecore.app.box.com/s/jqj8dkrmfiezrnwj42feop9jt1ff8km8

**Reference**

Link: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/1617